# Lambda Expressions - Concatenate Current and Next value

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I Have a List and i am trying to Concatenate the Current and the Next One. While i could easily again do this with the For loop by having item[Index] + item[Index +1] i wanted to try this with LINQ.

I tried with Aggregate and Next operators but they are giving me the whole Concatination.

```
if i have a List<string> ListSalary  that has value like 
"10000"
"20000"
"30000"
"40000"

I am looking for a output like 

"10,000 - 20,000"
"20,000 - 30,000"
"30,000 - 40,000"
```

My Forloop is

```
for (int index = 1; index < (ListSalary.Count - 1); index++) {
    txtSalary.text = ListSalary[index].valueName.ToString() + " To " + ListSalary[index +1].valueName.ToString() ;
}
```

Updated Question :

This is Giving me a List. I am not able to assign this to a Property of Class if i want to add something like

```
listSalaryProperty.AddRange(ListSalary.select(g=> new KeyValuePair
                        { 
                            key =  //  Here i want the 10,000 - 20,000
                            Value = // here it would be code value which  already have 
}
```

So here in key if i Use the snippet

```
key = ListSalary.Zip(ListSalary.Skip(1), (a, b) => string.Format("{0} - {1}", a, b))
            .ToList();
```

It will throw an Error of converting list To string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With LINQ, you can use [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the same collection, but without first element, so you will have access to both current and previous values:

```
var res = ListSalary.Zip(ListSalary.Skip(1), 
                         (a, b) => string.Format("{0} - {1}", a, b))
                    .ToList();
```

and given you want to project it to `KeyValuePair`, you can write:

```
listSalaryProperty.AddRange(
   ListSalary.Zip(ListSalary.Skip(1), 
                  (a, b) => new KeyValuePair<string, object>( 
                                                string.Format("{0} - {1}", a, b),
                                                /** your code **/)))
```

but change `object` to your type and add your code for calculating value of course.

Comment: This is Giving me a List. I am not able to assign this to a Property of Class if i want to add something like

Comment: @Karty, where do you want to assign it? It is not clear from your question.

Comment: Sorry.. I was typing and Hit the Enter button by mistake.. i have Updated my question

Answer (score 0):

```
ListSalary.Take( ListSalary.Count - 1 )
    .Select( (item, index) => string.Format( "{0} - {1}", item, ListSalary[index+1] ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listSalaryProperty.AddRange(
    ListSalary.Zip(ListSalary.Skip(1),
                   (a, b) => new
                             {
                                 From = a,
                                 To = b,
                                 Text = string.format("{0} - {1}", a, b)
                             }
             ).Select(g => new KeyValuePair<string, YourValueType>(
                                   g.Text,
                                   /* value code here */
                               )));
```

`KeyValuePair` is immutable, so you can't use object initialization syntax to initialize `Value` and `Key` properties (they are readonly). You have to use constructor instead. Change `YourValueType` to proper type which matches your value.

You can use `g.From`, `g.To` and `g.Text` (which holds your `XXX - YYY` string) to generate `Value`.